# Convert .png images to pdf in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf-generation

Am having a set of images in document directory path,i need to convert all of my saved images into pdf with page number.am using the following code for converting pdf
 
   `UIWebView *webview=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, 320,430)];
    pdfData = [PDFImageConverter convertImageToPDF: imageVIew.image
                          withHorizontalResolution: 550 verticalResolution: 320];
    NSString *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Documents/new.pdf"];
    NSLog(@"path %@",path);
    [pdfData writeToFile:path atomically:NO];
    [webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]]];
    [self.view addSubview:webview];`

In this code i can able to convert a single image into pdf.How to convert all of my images into pdf ?

Comment: Were you able to solve your issue? Can you please let me know how you achieved it. Coz am also trying something similar to your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the tutorial to generate PDF from image and other assets: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/generating-pdf-documents--mobile-11265 worked for me always.